# Android One Activity Transition Different Views

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, transition

I was wondering if someone can advise what the best way to do the following: I'm creating an application where I'm asking the user a question and the user either answers the question or proceeds to the next question with fade in and fade out animation using animator instead of anim. As of now, I have one activity and in the activity I would load the layout that I have created in XML and then remove the view and load a new view.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to present multiple views in one Activity and prevent the need to use multiple activities. The reason why I'm doing this is because I have several objects that I'm storing data into based on the category of the question (whether is math, science, social studies, etc).

Here is a picture if it helps visualize:
[image]

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. The only issue I'm having with this is that the activity A java class is growing in code because I have to handle everything there despite having the classes of the objects defined in other java files. Thank you.

Comment: see `android.transition.Scene` class

Comment: Thank pskink, I believe this is what I was looking for! Android Scene was built for this exact purpose. Here are two links that provide additional info about it: http://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3H7nJ4QaD8

Answer (score 1):

I think you can build layout like this
[RelativeLayout(see the structure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGpIE.png) Set layout1 android:visibility="visible" and layout2 android:visibility="invisible" at first in .xml

```
    layout1 = findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    layout2 = findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Button buttonNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewTransAnimation();
        }

    });
```

And set your animation in viewTransAnimation(), example:

```
private void viewTransAnimation() {
    layout2.setScaleX(0.1f);
    layout2.setPivotX(layout2.getX() + layout2.getLeft() );

    layout2.animate()
            .scaleX(1)
            .setDuration(500)
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
            .start();
}
```

Then it will change to layout2 after you click it. (use some flag make the animation only work once for your requirement.)

You can also replace 2 view with 2 RelativeLayout and do it in the same way.